# Displacement mesh looks shiny, does anyone know how to fix this?

Tags: mesh, displacement

I'm brand new to using Blender and I've run into something that I haven't had any luck finding a solution to so far, so I'm hoping someone may know how to fix this.

Using a displacement map, I created a displacement mesh with the displace and corrective smooth modifiers; there are no materials.  Everything seems to be working great, except the mesh looks shiny/glossy/metallic.  Is there anyone who knows how to get rid of/reduce the shininess?  Or is it normal for displacement meshes to look like this in Blender?  Thank you[image]

Comment: Hello, it looks like you are in Solid mode, it displays a default shading, but you have some options in the Viewport Shading panel (top right of your 3D view)

Comment: Go to the Material tab, Viewport display panel, and set Metallic to 0 and Roughness to 1.0.   This is not for rendering, it is only for the Solid view in the display.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using blender 3.0~3.1, and added the displacement using a modifier. And when you go to "Render", it looks shiny, glossy and metallic, am I not right?

If that's the case, select your object, go to the material tab. After that, reduce the option *Clearcoat* to 0.

If you're in *Solid* mode, then it's normal for it to look like this.

Comment: Since there wasn't a material applied to it I tried adding one, but upon adding it and adjusting the settings nothing about the appearance of the mesh changed.  I must be doing something wrong obviously, but I should've been more specific about what I'm trying to do with this mesh.  I want to bring it into Unreal Engine 5 and place a material on it there, but the shininess you see in Blender is showing up in Unreal Engine, which is why I believe it's the actual mesh itself that needs to be adjusted, rather than an adjustment to a material.  But that's just a guess.